# What is printing out when int pointer is printed with %d?

Tags: c, pointers

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    int *pi;
    num = 0;
    pi = &num;
    printf("address: %p | %d\nvalue: %d\n", pi, pi, *pi);
}
```

produces this output:

```
address: 0x7fff5952f9cc | 1498610124
value: 0
```

I know that the left one is supposed to be the correct address, but what is printing out next to the address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%p` tells `printf` to treat the corresponding variable as a pointer, thus `printf` prints `p` as a pointer; that is, a hexadecimal representation (i.e. `0x7fff5952f9cc`). `%d` on the other hand tells `printf` to treat the corresponding variable as numeric. Therefore, what is being printed is the *actual, numeric* value of `p` (i.e. `1498610124`) which is just 0x5952f9cc in base 10.

Now, the reason why these two representations of the same variable seem to have different values is that `%d` only tells `printf` to expect a number---it doesn't specify that number's type. If you cast 0x7fff5952f9cc (a 64-bit integer) to `int` (a 32-bit type) you get 1498610124 (notice `0x7fff` getting dropped).

Comment: _REMEMBER_: `sizeof(int*)` is _not_ guaranteed to be the same as `sizeof(int)` (even on a 32-bit processor)

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the address in decimal instead of in hex but it is truncated to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are executing this program on a `64bit` machine.

The number printed next to the address is still the address of the pointer printed in the integer format. **You can also see that the value is truncated**

decimal of `0x7fff5952f9cc` = `140734691998156`. but it is printed as `1498610124` which is due to truncation.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to print the address of num in hex and decimal value respectively. If I am not wrong you are running your program on a 64 bit architecture and hence the address will be of 8 bytes. So your address fits in long data type. By giving %d you are value is getting truncated here. Instead of %d please use %ld. So your printf of statement should be actually as below

printf("address: %p | %ld\nvalue: %d\n", pi, pi, *pi);

Now run the program you will get your value correctly in decimal format.

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything, because it's **Undefined Behaviour**. (C standard, § 7.21.6.1, *The fprintf function*):

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

You print `pi` (a pointer to an `int`) with two format specifiers, `%p` and `%d`. According to the C standard (and probably reproduced word for word in `man fprintf` on your system):

- `d,i` The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal in the style *[−]dddd*
- `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

So neither of those uses is correct. It's not a pointer to `void` and it's also not an `int`. So what you should write is:

```
printf("address: %p | %d\nvalue: %d\n", (void*)pi, (int)pi, *pi);
```

On your system, that probably produces the same output (**Undefined Behaviour** includes unexpectedly producing the incorrectly expected behaviour) but it might not. In any case, writing the line correctly makes it relatively clear what the second number printed is: it's the value of the pointer converted to an integer.

However, there is no guarantee that this will work, either. Again, from the standard (§6.3.2.3, *Pointers*, para. 6):

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

(The "previously specified" case is that a `NULL` pointer may reliably be converted to any integer type; it will have the value `0`.)

So the idea is that a pointer is a lot like an integer, but it might be the size of a `long`. Or a `long long`. Or something else. It might even be bigger than any integer type, but if there is some integer type which is the right size and you `#include <stdint.h>`, that integer type will be typedef'd to `intptr_t` and its unsigned version (probably more useful) will be `uintptr_t`. Unfortunately, there is no standard `printf` conversions for those sizes, so if you really want to, you would need to `#include <intypes.h>` and write:

```
printf("address: %p | %" PRIuPTR "\nvalue: %d\n",
       (void*)pi, (uintptr_t)pi, *pi);
```

Alternatively, because it is always allowed to convert any integer to any *unsigned* integer (with possible loss of information, but with a well-defined conversion), you could use two casts:

```
printf("address: %p | %u\nvalue: %d\n",
       (void*)pi, (unsigned)(uintptr_t)pi, *pi);
```

(Because that supplies an `unsigned int` argument, the format specifier must be `u` instead of `d`.)

Answer (score 0):

When using printf, the "p" modifier is intended to print out a memory address in hex format. The "d" modifier tells it to cast the value to a signed integer value. So it's taking 0x7fff5952f9cc and turning it into a signed int.

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more details on printf.

Answer (score 0):

In that code who have to print the address as the `%d` so during compile time it displayed warning and %p display the hexadecimal but %d display the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Its lower part – 4 least significant bytes – of the pointer value in decimal:
`0x5952F9CC == 1498610124`.